# Table with checkboxes losing its checked state on a page scroll (no lazy-loading or virtual scrolling is implemented) in react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, checkbox, html-table

I have a table in react js which has a column of checkboxes. On clicking the table header's checkbox, all of the children / table-row checkboxes gets checked. But when the table or page is scrolled. The checkboxes present in table row gets unchecked automatically, that is, the checked value is turning from `true` to `false`.
Below is the code:

```
<table className="table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td className="cell">
     <span className="select-all">
      <input onChange={selectAllClicked} type="checkbox" value="24">
     <span/>
   <td/>
  <tr/>
  <tr>
   <td className="cell">
     <span className="child-input">
      <input type="checkbox" value="24">
     <span/>
   <td/>
  <tr/>
  <tr>
   <td className="cell">
     <span className="child-input">
      <input type="checkbox" value="24">
     <span/>
   <td/>
  <tr/>
<tbody/>
```

Below is the event handler used:

```
function selectAllClicked() {
  $("span.child-input input").prop("checked", $(".select-all input").is(":checked"));
}
```

It would be really helpful if someone helps me in resolving this issue.